# ¿Son válidas las preguntas del tipo "explicadme esto" o "no entiendo tal cosa"?

Tags: discusión, preguntas, temática

He visto ya unas cuantas. Algunas incluso las he respondido, normalmente las que contienen código de una sola línea y no tenían mucho *rollo* que soltar.

Pero... ¿son válidas?

1. No tienen trabajo de investigación. El código **no es** del OP (dudo mucho que alguien pueda hacer un código funcional sin saber lo que está haciendo).
2. Las que tienen más de 1 o 2 líneas, suelen implicar mas de una pregunta. Esto hace tal cosa, lo otro sirve para esto, lo demás hace lo otro... Podría decirse que *no está claro lo que se pregunta*, o *son demasiado amplias*.
3. No se indica la diferencia entre lo que se obtiene y lo que se esperaba obtener.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yo creo que depende mucho de la actitud del OP.

Si el usuario es nuevo y es evidente que no ha realizado el recorrido, creo que podríamos invitarlo a que lo revise y darle la chance de editar su pregunta y completar toda la información que se espera. He visto casos de personas que cometen este error pero sí tienen ganas de aprender, así que creo que debemos tener cuidado de no espantarlos.

A esto, en mi opinión enteramente personal, creo que se le debe dar al OP un espacio para revisar el tour, reflexionar al respecto y editar la pregunta. Mi idea siempre ha sido esperar alrededor de 12 horas porque puede que el OP esté al otro lado del mundo, escribió la pregunta y se fue a dormir, posiblemente cansado y agobiado por un mal día que terminó en frustración por no poder resolver su problema de programación. ¿Por qué lo pienso así? Porque lo he hecho.

Si después de ese tiempo, el OP no muestra señales de interés, cerrarle la pregunta.

Ahora, también he visto personas que quieren deliberadamente que les hagan el trabajo. Ellos son fáciles de detectar. Les pones comentarios y no responden. Pero ni bien aparece una respuesta que les da una pista para resolver el problema comienzan a lanzar preguntas que demuestran que *no quiere entender el problema, tampoco la solución, solo quieren copiar, pegar y presentar*. Ante esos casos, si yo he respondido la pregunta, sinceramente me sentiría indignado y la borraría para no ayudarle a un (...) flojo/a, votaría negativo y pondría un voto de cierre.

Comment: Hay un círculo eseñpecial en el infierno para los que solo quieren que les haga uno el trabajo. Pero hay un demonio particular esperando en ese círculo a los que además de querer que les soluciones el problema con código efectivo, creen que uno no se da cuenta que los ejemplos que ponen son exploits, shellcode y en general código malicioso. Encima osan aclarar que "solo es curiosidad de ver los efectos de distintos regex en documentos RTF" cuando el mismo snippet que pegaron dice en los comentarios en inglés "ofusca tu código malicioso aquí" xD un ejemplo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/106235

Answer (score 3):

Yo me he encontrado casos en los que considero muy válidas estas preguntas: Son gente que está aprendiendo un lenguaje de programación y se ponen a mirar código de otros para aprender diferentes técnicas. A menudo se encuentran trozos de código crípticos, y no saben cómo buscar en Google respuestas porque incluyen símbolos que el navegador ignora si no usas comillas para buscarlos (cosas como `|` , `~`, `&`, `^`, `->`, ...) .