# ¿Es off-topic una pregunta que pide aclaración sobre alguna función especifica?

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas, pregunta-específica

Esta revisando en respuestas en SO y encontré la siguiente publicación:

[¿Cual es la diferencia entre rand y srand?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/183044/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-rand-y-srand)

Para mí la pregunta es correcta porque se enmarca en pedir aclaración sobre una función donde probablemente la documentación usa muchos tecnicismos causando la confusión de un principiante.

Un usuario comentó [en una respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/183056/22539) que la pregunta es demasiado amplia porque no se enmarca en un código específico. Yo estoy de acuerdo en que un código específico haría mucho más precisa la pregunta, pero ello no implica que la pregunta actual sea demasiado amplia. Despues, él sustentó que esta pregunta podria causar que las respuestas estén basadas en opiniones, y para mí no lo es porque se enmarcan en la documentación.

Pero lo que a mi preocupa es que el usuario indicó que preguntas similares han generado el cierre de las preguntas incluso por algunos de los moderadores. Mi pregunta es: ¿este tipo de preguntas debe ser cerrada?

Comment: Actualmente la pregunta no tiene comentarios ni votos de cierre, la puntuación es +1. ¿Han sido eliminados los comentarios a los que te referías o son los que se han publicado en alguna de las respuestas?

Comment: @Rubén el usuario elimino el voto de cierre pero por presión, no porque estaba convencido, los comentarios no estan debajo de la pregunta sino de una respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/183056/22539, y el usuario se puede decir que no es un novato ya que tiene cierta reputacion en SOes, por ello mi interés en realizar esta pregunta

Comment: @Rubén mi pregunta va en el sentido que este tipo de preguntas son válidas y que no toda pregunta necesita de un [mcve]

Comment: Al autor del comentario en cuestión se le podría decir que las respuestas no son lugar para criticar las preguntas, eso se hace en las preguntas :)

Comment: Si esta pregunta va en el sentido mencionado en el comentario, deberías mencionarlo en la pregunta :)

Comment: Relacionado: 1) [¿Son aceptables las preguntas conceptuales?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/115/65) 2) [¿Son válidas las preguntas del tipo “explicadme esto” o “no entiendo tal cosa”?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2808/65)

Comment: Es el tipo de pregunta que se resuelve con un [RTM](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM)... por desgracia no suele haber documentación en español sobre programación, por suerte existe SOes.

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus exacto, si existiese documentación oficial en español esas preguntas no tendrían sentido, pero desgraciadamente no las hay, o son escazas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esa pregunta es válida.. con un poco mas de contexto.

Está pidiendo una aclaración, pero ella no aclara lo suficiente que entendió de cada función. Hubiera estado mejor la pregunta si se aclaraba que se había averiguado, leído u observado y porque no se entendía el comportamiento (para colmo, son dos funciones que se llaman casi igual, pero no hacen lo mismo).

Quien comentó sobre la respuesta, debería haberlo hecho sobre la pregunta. En ese caso hubiera estado bien avisarle a un **MOD**, para que moviera los comentarios a donde correspondía.

A quien respondió, también se le podría haber sugerido que mejorara un poco la pregunta.

A quien preguntó, se le podría haber pedido que aunque estuviera contestada, agregara algo de contexto (aunque pareciera tonto, a veces para un novato ese contexto es todo).

Por ejemplo:

> Porque si hago Srand() el numero que me devuelve es distinto siempre,
>   pero si hago Srand(1) siempre me devuelve el mismo?

Hacer varias preguntas sobre el mismo contexto en una pregunta está bien.

Comment: Si pides a alguien que hagas algo que parece tonto es porque... es tonto (el algo) o no se lo has explicado bien.